# Write to user defined partition /data

Tags: partitioning, permissions, xubuntu, 14.04

I'm a newbie in Linux/Ubuntu/Xubuntu world.

In order to supply data encapsulation I defined separate partition `/data` on my HDD, where I want to store all my user data, separately from system-related data, this will allow me to format/reinstall Ubuntu without any issue.

I enter into `/data/` and find out, that I don't have permissions to write to this folder. How can I enable it? I want to have ability to store all my data in this path and to have ability to format/remove & recreate other partitions.

Comment: Why you choose the `/` root directory to store your personal datas?

Comment: Normally, `/home` is responsible for keeping all your user's data. You probably should place it on separate partition.

Comment: @AvinashRaj he said separate partition so it is not in `/` ;-)

Comment: post the output of `sudo blkid` command.

Comment: @Danatela, I want to store all my data in complete system installation independent place, to be sure that in case of any crisis my data won't be affected by OS or installer either. E.g. if I will broke the installation I want to have ability just to remove all partitions except of "/data" and install OS again. Does "/home" contains any system installation related data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /data
```

This will change the directory and all files in it to your user. $USER will automagically changed to your current user so you can copy/paste this as is.

Comment: I will have to do this step each time I reinstall OS with complete disk formatting? If I will use /home instead I will not should to do this?

Comment: Yes to the 1st question. If you format it will be mounted as root as default; And yes to the 2nd. /home/$USER/ is assumed to by owned by $USER